# WPF Button doesn't execute Command

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, event-handling, listviewitem

I have a `ListViewItem` which has an `Eventhandler` attatched and inside the `ControlTemplate` of the `ListViewItem` is a `Button` which does something different. But if I click the `Button`, the Behaviour is like I clicked on the `ListViewItem`.

**AppointmentOverview.xaml:**

```
<Window.Resources>        
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource NormalListViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
            Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Styles.xaml**(My ResourceDictionary)**:**

```
<!--Style für die normalen ListViewItems-->
<Style x:Key="NormalListViewItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">       
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border BorderBrush="#5076A7" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFEB603" Offset="1.0"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <StackPanel TextElement.FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextElement.FontSize="12">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Name="Betreff" Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Betreff}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemButton}"/>
```

**AppointmentOverview.xaml.cs:**

```
private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as ListViewItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        AppointmentOverviewViewModel apvm = this.DataContext as AppointmentOverviewViewModel;
        apvm.editAppointment(item);
    }
}
```

It worked when I had the complete `ListViewItem` `Style` in the `Window.Resource`s of Appointmentoverview.xaml. But I didn't like that because the would kind of beat the purpose of Styles.xaml. Also I didn't have a `Style` for the `Button`, just did all the `Styling` inside the `Button`. But this was very Basic and now I need more complex `Styling` so I wanted to create a separate `Style`.

```
<Button FontSize="7" Content="X" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteButtonCommand, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ItemId}"/>
```

---

**Update:**
If I observe my EventHandler this is also triggered if the Button is pressed. It just says the source is a Button but the command is not executed.

**Styles.xaml.cs**

```
void ListViewItem_MouseLeftDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject current = sender as DependencyObject;
        while (current != null && current.GetType() != typeof(ListViewItem))
        {
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }
        var item = current as ListViewItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            Window parent = Window.GetWindow(current);
            AppointmentOverviewViewModel apovm = parent.DataContext as AppointmentOverviewViewModel;
            apovm.editAppointment(item);
        }

    }
```

**Styles.xaml**

```
<!--DataTemplate für die normalen ListViewItems-->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SCSMAppointment}">
    <Border BorderBrush="#5076A7" BorderThickness="1" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListViewItem_MouseLeftDown">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFEB603" Offset="1.0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <Button FontSize="7" Content="X" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="15"
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ItemId}"/>
                <TextBlock Name="Betreff" Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Betreff}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />

            </DockPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Kunde}"/>
                <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="|"/>
                <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding IncidentId}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Ort}"/>
                <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="("/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Alternative}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=")"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>        
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Why are you using a `ControlTemplate` for your `ListViewItem`? Surely, you should be declaring what your data objects look like in a `DataTemplate` set to the `ItemTemplate` property instead.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm new to WPF/Templating and this has always worked for me so far. I was just wodnering why the `Button` stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

It is apparent that your XAML is not correct.  A [`ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) is primarily used to *Specify the visual structure and behavioral aspects of a `Control` that can be shared across multiple instances of the control.* In plain English, that means that they are used to change the default look of a *`Control`*. If that is not what you are doing, then you should not be using them.

On the other hand, [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)s *Describe the visual structure of a data object*, so you should be declaring `DataTemplate`s to define what your data looks like instead of using `ControlTemplate`s. Therefore, I suggest that you read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, which will give you a much better understanding, *before* you continue to work with WPF.

When you have updated your project, your problem will probably fix itself, but if it doesn't please return here to edit your question with your new XAML.

Comment: I have updated my Project. But now only the `ControlTemplate` is visible. So just the `Background` is changed but no `Data` is visible.

Comment: Once again, you shouldn't be using a `ControlTemplate`. I provided you with several links to help you, but it appears that you have completely ignored them, so I'm not sure it's worth responding to your comments any more. You *cannot* learn WPF on this website... that's your job.

Comment: I'm sorry I asked to quickly. But now I have put everything into a `Datatemplate` but still when I click the `Button` the behaviour is like clicking on the `Ite`m. If I disable the `EventHandler` it works.